# how to use network connectivity plugin in background process in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to use connectivity plugin in background process? 
I don't know how to call dart code in background there is little about this in docs.
I need this functionality to sync offline data with backend whenever there is a connection wether app is in foreground or background and app is in killed state like the way Whatsapp syncs messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing plugins for background execution (on android & ios usually in a roughly 15 minute interval)

https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

There is also a article dedicated to using isolates for background executions

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes
https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124

Comment: background_fetch is for periodic tasks I need a listener like broadcastreceiver in android

Comment: @monajafi iOS is very restrictive about background use, I don't think you'll be able to listen to every state change in the background and perform an action instantly. The android part you can probably solve by writing a plugin yourself that uses the broadcastreciever. The whole use-case sounds odd and like a battery eater tho, you should consider the periodic solution.

Comment: I've found a plugin called workmanager which is a wrapper around android workmanager and iOS' performFetchWithCompletionHandler. In android we can create  OneTimeTask and set constraint on NetworkType.connected whenever there is a connection we can sync data. If iOS has restricted background usage how firebase manages device data sync after gaining connectivity? Whatsapp is sending cached messages whenever device get connected to internet even in the killed state.

Comment: @monajafi Whatsapp is sending push notifications, those get delivered by apple once the device gets internet access. Firebase probably sync's with the background fetch, whent the app is active it uses a websocket to handle the sync state.

Comment: @monajafi Did you got any solution