# Check internet connectivity while the app is closed in flutter Android

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

I'm working on an app which stores data on servers, And the app is available offline too.

When user gets back online after being offline. I need to update servers with changes he done while being offline. Any workaround? I hear that after android O its not possible

Comment: you can save these change in Storage locally. and when application gets start check if anything exists in storage send it to server.

Answer (score 1):

Check this package.
You can check the network status using this plugin. It also have stream for network connection so, when your user becomes online you can trigger your task.

https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus

Comment: Thanks for answer! I already use this package to detect network changes while the app is running. I was asking for when the app is closed, or in background. Like in whatsapp and such messenger apps

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch
 and 
https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

These two plugin can help you to achieve background work.
workmanager have NetworkType.connected  event which can be useful for your case.

There is another  thread for your issue,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552222/how-to-use-network-connectivity-plugin-in-background-process-in-flutter

Comment: Whoa! Exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pakage for check your internet connection. you can also configure to lookup internet availability in a periodic interval.
[flutter_network_connectivity: ^0.0.6](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_network_connectivity)

```
import 'package:flutter_network_connectivity/flutter_network_connectivity.dart';
```

Create an Object

```
FlutterNetworkConnectivity flutterNetworkConnectivity =
    FlutterNetworkConnectivity(
      isContinousLookUp: true,  // optional, false if you cont want continous lookup
      lookUpDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5),  // optional, to override default lookup duration
      lookUpUrl: 'example.com',  // optional, to override default lookup url
);


_flutterNetworkConnectivity.getInternetAvailabilityStream().listen((isInternetAvailable) {
  // do something
});
```

[image]